# OCaml, unexpected behavior with refs and trees

Tags: debugging, tree, ocaml, ref

I was trying to assign a number to each element of a tree. I thought using `refs` would make the task easier, but I encountered a strange behavior : the numbers assigned were not unique and no clear pattern emerged. I managed to fix the bug (adding the `let unboxed = !second_ref in` line) but I do not understand what happened.

The first tree in the output console just makes sure the `print_tree` function outputs what it should.

However, the output expected for the second print should be exactly the same one as the third tree. What am I missing ?

```
type ('a, 'b) tree =
  | Node of 'a * ('a, 'b) tree * ('a, 'b) tree
  | Leaf of 'b

let print_tree tree string_of_node string_of_leaf  =
  let rec print indent tree =
    match tree with
    | Leaf (l) -> print_string (indent^" -> "^string_of_leaf(l)^"\n")
    | Node (n, left, right) ->
      Printf.printf "%s-----------\n" indent;
      print (indent ^ "|         ") left;
      Printf.printf "%s%s\n" indent (string_of_node(n));
      print (indent ^ "|         ") right;
      Printf.printf "%s-----------\n" indent
  in print "" tree 

let myTree = Node(1,Node(2,Leaf(3),Leaf(4)),Node(5,Leaf(6),Leaf(7))) ;;

let first_ref = ref 0 ;;
let rec bug tree = 
  first_ref := !first_ref+ 1;
  match tree with
  |Leaf(a) -> Leaf(!first_ref)
  |Node(n,l,r) -> Node(!first_ref, bug l, bug r) ;;

let second_ref = ref 0 ;;
let rec bug_fixed tree = 
  second_ref := !second_ref + 1;
  let unboxed = !second_ref in
  match tree with
  |Leaf(a) -> Leaf(unboxed)
  |Node(n,l,r) -> Node(unboxed, bug_fixed l, bug_fixed r) ;;


let bug_tree = bug myTree ;;
let bug_fixed_tree = bug_fixed myTree ;;

print_tree myTree string_of_int string_of_int ;
print_tree bug_tree string_of_int string_of_int ;
print_tree bug_fixed_tree string_of_int string_of_int ;
```

The output is the following :

```
-----------
|         -----------
|         |          -> 3
|         2
|         |          -> 4
|         -----------
1
|         -----------
|         |          -> 6
|         5
|         |          -> 7
|         -----------
-----------
-----------
|         -----------
|         |          -> 7
|         7
|         |          -> 6
|         -----------
7
|         -----------
|         |          -> 4
|         4
|         |          -> 3
|         -----------
-----------
-----------
|         -----------
|         |          -> 7
|         5
|         |          -> 6
|         -----------
1
|         -----------
|         |          -> 4
|         2
|         |          -> 3
|         -----------
-----------
```

Comment: This is probably off-topic here, but your definition of the type `tree` puzzles me. The leaves may have a different type than the nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `bug` function, there's this problematic expression:

```
Node(!first_ref, bug l, bug r)
```

Its behaviour depends on the order of evaluation of the arguments: `bug l` and `bug r` increment `first_ref`, so the value that is passed may not be what you want.

You can force the order by doing for example:

```
let v = !first ref in
let new_l = bug l in
let new_r = bug r in
Node (v, new_l, new_r)
```

Comment: Just to add a bit of context to this answer. Theoretically, order of evaluation does not matter in a pure functional language, thanks to the absence of side-effects. Of course, using references breaks this situation,  hence the local binding trick. It's worth noting that order of evaluation is not specified in OCaml, which is in accordance with the language's functional nature.

Comment: @RichouHunter, OCaml is far from being pure and has plenty of other effects besides mutable state, e.g. exceptions, non-termination, I/O, etc. So IMHO there is no excuse for not specifying evaluation order. It's one of its most annoying pitfalls.

Comment: I totally agree, @AndreasRossberg. I wonder what the impact of specifying it now would be on existing implementations and code base, though.

Comment: @RichouHunter, theoretically, it could only affect programs that are currently buggy.